# Expanding OnClick a single div with rearranging the rest

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4, transform

everyone !
So what I have in mind is to have a div class= container with 2 rows of 3 cards within it .

**I am using bootstrap 4 as my grid and layout.**

Card examples: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

```
<div class="container>
  <div class="row>
    <card-element />
    <card-element />
    <card-element />
    <card-element />
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically these 4 elements again are divs with other divs in them to distribute the content f.x  at the top with a  and  for description.

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is that when I click on any of these  s the one that I have clicked should go ahead and expand in the middle when the others are done moving to either the left or right side of the container element and resizing to a smaller size (like a thumbnail but very small). 
So far I've tried using transform and translate for expansion, however I cannot figure out how to mix and match the two of the functionalities.

I have thought of having a couple of JQuery functions within these steps : 
1.Onclick- The selected element expands while all other elements are .remove() by JQuery.
2.Once it expands the other elements get appended to 2 sides - let's say 2 divs within the container positioned to be on the left and right end of it. Of course the appending is done exact to either side div. 
 3. The transition that supposedly happens is the other card-element thumbnails dissapear eased-in/out and appear once the .append function is done.

Any ideas would help or any reference to a similair problem/task would be of great help.

Comment: Could you share your javascript as well?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, refine the specific question and show the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jquery-UI](https://jqueryui.com/), there are a component called accordion, it works like:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Card 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Text of card 1...
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Card 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
      Text of card 2...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that accordion, however that's not the problem with the expansion of the content itself. It is with resizing the cards and placing them to the left and right side of the container once one of them expands with content. Transform and translate is probably require, however I also researched with JS if it's possible to .append and .remove them and add completely different styles to the markup once it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap Collapse component and jQuery to toggle the CSS classes. For example...

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.collapse.show').not(this).collapse("hide");
  $(this).parents('.col-sm').toggleClass("col-sm-6 col-sm");
  $(this).parents('.card-body').find('.col-12').toggleClass("col col-12");
});

$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).parents('.col-sm-6').toggleClass("col-sm col-sm-6");
  $(this).parents('.card-body').find('.col').toggleClass("col-12 col");
});
```

And then add some CSS transformations as the classes change...

```
.row > [class*="col"], img{
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/emFWdeJQgS

Of course you'll have to make some mods to get it exactly as desired.